# Proper way to work with viewport on cordova

Tags: html, cordova, viewport

I can't understand the proper way to work with `<meta>` viewport on cordova.
My `window.innerWidth` is always `320px` (`"device-width"`).
Even if I use:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=600, user-scalable=no'>
```

That seems too small. And of course I want better resolution.
But I can't find a proper way to change it from cordova out of the box.
 I have found some advice such as at this page - https://github.com/cakuki/cordova-plugin-viewport.
But I find it strange that I need to install plugin or change java template code for such a common thing.
Is  there any proper way to increase screen width?
Why does cordova think I need only `"width=device-width"` value?

Thank you!

Comment: I cant speak for cordova, but `width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0` is by far the most common viewport setting for responsive pages. Can you further explain why this setting is causing you troubles, and therefore not an option?

Comment: When I make JS canvas to fullscreen it has only 320px width. But when viewport width is equal to my screen resolution I have bigger canvas and better quality of picture on it.